# Swift: cannot subscript value of [String:NSObject] with index of type?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

Ok, I am working with MPMediaItems here and I need to get an image from an MPMediaItemArtwork. Problem is since Im using another framework, this [imageWithSize in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689805/imagewithsize-in-swift3/39689868#39689868) is not working for me. My MPMediaItem seems to be in a different format:

```
 if let artWork = AudioPlayerManager.shared.currentTrack?.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemArtwork] as? MPMediaItemArtwork {
            trackImg = artWork.image(at: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))!
            print("IMG: ",trackImg)
        }
```

Nothing is printed and I get error:

```
cannot subscript value of [String:NSObject] with index of type MPMediaItemArtwork.Type
```

What does this mean? How can I get the image into a UIImage from here?

Within the framework, the guy has:

```
fileprivate func extractMetadata() {
        Log("Extracting meta data of player item with url: \(url)")
        for metadataItem in (self.playerItem?.asset.commonMetadata ?? []) {
            if let _key = metadataItem.commonKey {
                switch _key {
                case AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle       : self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = metadataItem.stringValue as NSObject?
                case AVMetadataCommonKeyAlbumName   : self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = metadataItem.stringValue as NSObject?
                case AVMetadataCommonKeyArtist      : self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = metadataItem.stringValue as NSObject?
                case AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork     :
                    if
                        let _data = metadataItem.dataValue,
                        let _image = UIImage(data: _data) {
                            self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = self.mediaItemArtwork(from: _image)
                    }
                default                             : continue
                }
            }
        }
        // Inform the player about the updated meta data
        AudioPlayerManager.shared.didUpdateMetadata()
    }

    fileprivate func mediaItemArtwork(from image: UIImage) -> MPMediaItemArtwork {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size: CGSize) -> UIImage in
                return image
            })
        } else {
            return MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what framework are you using?  is it open source (so I or somebody else can peek at it?)? is `nowPlayingInfo` exposed as a `[String:NSObject]` dictionary or something else?

Comment: The error says that `nowPlayingInfo` is a dictionary that's keyed by strings.  You're trying to get information using a key that's not a string.  I don't know anything about this dictionary, but I notice there's a related symbol called `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` which **is** a string.

Comment: Philip Mills is correct. In the `extractMetadata` method you can clearly see that the image is stored under the key `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` and that it is of type `MPMediaItemArtwork`. In your code you are confusing the key `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` and the type `MPMediaItemArtwork`. Change your code to: `if let artWork = AudioPlayerManager.shared.currentTrack?.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] as? MPMediaItemArtwork { // ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nowPlayingInfo` dictionary is declared as `[String:NSObject]` so you clearly you need to use a `String` as a key.

But you are trying to use things like `MPMediaItemArtwork` which is a class name.

The list of valid keys can be found by reading the Overview for the [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter) class (which is where `nowPlayingInfo` is declared). As you can see, the keys can be found from the [`MPMediaItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/general_media_item_property_keys) documentation.

So you need to replace `MPMediaItemArtwork` with `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`.